# Why normalize function has a different result on a matrix vs single value?

Tags: data, data-cleaning, normalization, matlab

I have a matrix like:

```
B=[ 1.5035; 1.5728; 1.6485;  1.5369;  1.5467;  1.572; 1.5374;  1.787;  1.5825; 1.6905];
```

Using normalize function like  normalize(B,'range') has this result:

```
ans =  0
  0.24444
  0.51146
  0.11781
  0.15238
  0.24162
  0.11958
        1
  0.27866
  0.65961
```

But when I use it for a single value like:

```
normalize(B(2,:),'range')
```

the result is 0 , but the result for row number 2 in ans is  0.24444.
Why its different and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normalize function works by calculating z-score for the given data. Now z-score is given by:
$$z_{i} = \frac{x_{i} - mean(X)}{s.d.(X)}$$
where $X$ is your original vector/matrix.

Now, when you give a vector as input it first calculates the mean and standard deviation for the row/column. Then the output you ask for is calculated the above formula. So, if you only ask for a scalar it only shows one value. You can see in your example the normalized value(or z-score) is same for that particular position i.e. $0.24444$.

But when you give only a single value as input the z-score is 0 by definition. For more on it's working and use take a look at the [docs](https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.normalize.html).